# UI interfaces animation is gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating an iOS project and are using some of the UI like Alert popup. In the beginning when activating the Alerts it popped up with a smooth animation. But suddenly there is no animations...? Even when I activate a web view it normally scrolled down from the top but now it just is there. Has anyone experinced this, and if yes... How to solve???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "UI like Alert popup"?  Are you using `UIAlertView` or not?

Comment: Can you show some code? Likely you're stacking animations somehow.

Comment: Where should I be looking. A novice with xCode :-/